# How do you increase the number of worlds you can share?

Tags: project-spark

At the moment I can only have a maximum of three worlds uploaded at the same time. Is there a way to increase this number? I am at Spark level 11 if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them with Spark Premium or you can find them in some of the packs you can get from the Marketplace. I noticed one of the Champions Quest ones has 3 extra upload slots available that come with it.

Comment: That is correct. Well done :)